# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'I005' SQL Y PYTHON

Tags: python, sql

estoy creando un programa de escritorio. En el cual quiero asociar una consulta a SQL (utilizando xampp) por medio de un botón (tkinter) para poder eliminar una fila de la tabla, pero al ejecutar el código

```
def eliminar():
id = tabla_1.selection()[0]
if int(id)>0:
    sql="DELETE from tabla1 where id ="+id 
    db.cursor.execute(sql)
    db.connection.commit() #confirmar
    tabla_1.DELETE(id)
```

Me figura este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de un vídeo y está todo tal cual, capto que el error está en la 3ra linea, pero no entiendo cómo poder solucionarlo, alguna ayuda por favor? :(

PD: es mi primer programa en python

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código y los errores como texto, no como imagen

Comment: No te confies en las ids defaults del treeview. Para empezar son alfanumericas y NO siguen el formato I(numero item). Por ejemplo el item 10 NO es i010.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta pasando es que estas intentando hacer una string "I005" a integer pero "I" no lo puedes transformar a numero...

El la linea 40 lo estas haciendo, intenta debugar la app y ver en que punto aparece este valor "I005" y antes de pasarlo por la funcion de int() darle un formato que se puede transformar tipo "005" ahora tu sabras como tiene que ser  la id de la DB

https://www.w3resource.com/python/built-in-function/int.php